# Uploading Multiple Files with Long File Names

Tags: php, html

I use the following html and php code to select and upload multiple files.

HTML

```
 <form action="uploadFiles.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple"/></br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit[]" value="submit" />
 </form>
```

uploadFiles.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
       if ($_FILES["file[]"]["error"] > 0)
       {
            echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file[]"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            $numFilesUploaded=count($_FILES['file']['name']);
            echo "No. files uploaded : ".$numFilesUploaded."<br><br>";
            for ($inc=0; $inc<$numFilesUploaded; ++$inc){
                echo "File " . $inc . ": " . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$inc] . "<br>";
                echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$inc] . "<br>";
                echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"][$inc] . "<br>";
                echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"][$inc] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
                echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$inc];
                echo "<br><br>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

If I select 2 files, each having names of character length 8, the code works fine.  However, when I select files with names of character length 32, $_POST is an empty array.  What is the best way to upload multiple files where the file names may be long?

Comment: Are you sure it's the file name that's the problem and not the file's size? Does your web server happen to be running something like the  [Suhosin extension?](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/) (I think `phpinfo()` should tell you)

Comment: I ran phpinfo() and it did indeed say "This server is protected with the Suhosin Patch 0.9.10 ..."  However I think it is the length of the file names rather than the files themselves because I have not yet gotten to the point of trying to upload the files.  I am only trying to post the file names to the PHP script.  No file names are actually posted if the names are too long.

Comment: try to upload file that's having 8 char file name but having larger file size...

Comment: It may be a Suhosin setting then, but I can't see any such setting in the config: http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html

Comment: You are correct.  I tried large files with short names and small files with long names.  The small files with long names produced no problems.  The large files with short names produced Array() when I used echo "uploadFiles.php <br>"; in the PHP script.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as PHP concerns, File name is not a problem, Make sure your

```
upload_max_filesize
max_post_size
```

are set appropriately in php.ini file, If you try to upload files larger than tha size, You will not be able to upload the file. So double check them.